# Connecting from Aritfactory to LDAP

Tags: ldap, artifactory, apacheds

I configured a connexion to an LDAP server from Artifactory interface, when I try to "authenticate" a USER FOR TEST (xtest), the authentication fails.

=> I am using LDAP "perspective" on Eclipse Oxygen

=> I implemented the LDAP server using ApacheDS

Here's the Directory Information Tree (DIT)

[DIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUdYR.png)

And here's the configuration on Arti interface

[Config part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngLsU.png)

[Config part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lybx.png)

Is there a wrong "input" in the configuration? 
Also, would you please explain the role of "search filter" and "search base" and if they are configured the right way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What objectclasses are defined on xtest? The DN is uid=xtest,ou=xgroupe,dc=example,dc=com and it seems suspect to authenticate a group.

To answer your other questions, search base is the part of the tree to include in the search, eg. ou=xgroupe,dc=example,dc=com. Search filter is where you would include object class and attribute information, eg. (&(objectclass=person)(uid={0}).

If what you are searching for is not on the branch of the tree in the search base or it does not fulfill the filter, it will not be found.